# Inexpensive field deployable non-invasive current sensor

Tags: current, sensor, current-measurement, mains, current-sensing

Is there an inexpensive way to [MacGyver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGyver#MacGyverisms) a non-invasive current sensor together in a field (yes, a literal field), assuming some prior planning?

The context here is an event similar to [EMF Camp](https://www.emfcamp.org/) or [OHM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observe._Hack._Make.), at which they run a couple of large diesel generators and distribute power around the camp via [Commando plugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60309) and consumer socket breakouts inside porta-loos.

I'd like to be able to turn up to an existing system, non-invasively attach or wrap a sensor around a cable (possibly up to 1.5" diameter) and measure the current being pulled on that line. The sensed current would then be transmitted by a LoRa module to a base station which then maps the power usage across the site.

Accuracy isn't particularly critical as I'm mostly looking to track the variation (deltas) of power, so a constant offset of even several amps is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It unlikely to find a solution if the wires are bundled into a plug.  The current must be measure by putting a current probe completely around only 1 wire , either Line or Neutral, ( aka an current sensor and DMM) which is an easy connection but only if an open wire length accessible.

Comment: Get an old transformer [ E-I or C-I ] and remove the I. Place the open gap against the power cord/cable, and rotate around the cable to find the maximum voltage. There should be 2, but with opposite polarity (I bet you don't care about that).

Comment: Power does not equate to current.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm aware of that, but the voltage is known.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 There are solutions (see: [this from SparkFun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11005)) but they don't appear to be physically large enough for my needs.

Comment: And I guess you know the relative phase angle of current to voltage too?

Comment: @Andyaka No idea, though the linked SparkFun product doesn't seem to assume that knowledge, particularly if only differentials are being calculated and accuracy isn't critical. Is it wrong in this regard? I feel like your question is a leading one, but I'm not sure what conclusion you're trying to lead me to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhwfs7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Your Sparkfun probe with suitable burden resistor and recording interface is the ideal cheap Ammeter probe for 30A suitable for 1cm wire including insulation.

I hope it is obvious why your 1.5" bundle does not work, because the currents cancel when sensing both wires together from the loop current in both wires.

To make this work, each output must be "invaded" to bring out an insulated wire for clamping the probe. Where and how you do this may not be feasible.

To avoid the "trade-show" blues, it may be more sensible to measure the current at the distribution panel where the wires are accessible at the fuse panel.  Then measure voltage drop at the end-points. Normally drop in a well designed distribution network is 0 to 5% and another 5% at source.  Variations > 10% voltage may indicate excess ratio of Amps to Ampacity or load for the cable length and gauge.

> If you network measurements of end-point voltages and current at breaker for each end point, you will have better luck determining who is drawing too much power if you have a power layout schematic or wiring table.

Details on deployment depend on access points, qty, and cost of ***not managing power outages*** to prevent "trade-show blues".

Comment: I can only imagine excess power in a porta-loo. Maybe.  Somehow methane gas and a spark does not seem like a smart idea as someone fatally discovered in Perth a couple years ago.

Comment: Haha! In this case it's just the case of a porta-loo without any chemicals or human byproducts, which works as a convenient way to keep power distribution and networking gear dry and secure. It's actually perfect width for rackmount gear, and they've even developed a status LED stick which attaches to the top so it can be diagnosed at a distance. They've been using these things for nearly a decade now to good effect.

Comment: Your answer is useful, though. I forgot that clamping to the full-size cable would cause me to get the cancelled out signal, which is largely useless. Unfortunately I'm not directly involved with the power team or the NOC, so I wouldn't be able to get any kind of in-line access to power information - I was hoping to just turn up and clip a sensor on without bothering anyone. Never mind!

Comment: then what service can you hope to achieve without access? One can only make a cheater cord to measure one's own current and voltage.

Comment: The equipment is accessible physically, and I can obtain permission to add an unintrusive sensor device, but I have no say in how it is configured or deployed. The whole event is a meeting of makers, hackspace members, tinkerers, etc. so this sort of idea is the norm.

Comment: so what is the point?

Comment: The plan was to have a real-time map of power consumption across the camp by hooking current sensors to each main "branch" of distributed mains, then make that accessible to anyone who was interested. I've been playing with LoRa modules recently so I thought it'd be a nice use-case.

Comment: then my suggestion works best. Current sense on breakers and voltage sense to end points of interest on same breakers.